# CSS Child Container Behind Parent With Matching Height

Tags: html, css

I have container A.

I'd like container A to be behind container B.

Container A must have a height equal to that of container B.

Their width is fixed.

Container A's shadow must not affect container B's border.

At the moment, I tried using absolute positioning but don't know how to fix the height issue.

```
#A {
    position:relative;
    max-width:800px;
    border: an image with transparent parts ;
}

#B {
    position:absolute;
    max-width:800px;
    height:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 26px 8px #000;
    background:red; #should not be visible
}
```

The code above does what I want except that the border of A is messed up by the shadow of B.

Comment: *I tried using absolute positioning* -> Can you post your code so that others can debug? Also, will be helpful if you share an image of how you expect it to be

Comment: @Lolums please put code with the question, what you have tried so far

Comment: What is the purpose of having two separate divs? The way I see it, you can set a shadow on container B and no container A at all...

Comment: @LinkinTED I have an image border, part of which is transparent and the shadow starts after the image border. It looks bad. The shadow has to start after the box, not the border

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil there isn't too much to share

Comment: @Mr.Alien it's just an ordinary box (that has a border image with transparent parts) with a shadow. The shadow has to start at the box, not at the border.

Comment: The content is in container B?

Comment: @LinkinTED Nah, content is in A and B just acts as a shadow for A, so B has to be as large as A, excluding A's border

Comment: Please add the HTML and an image of the desired result... it's all too vague to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but shouldn't it be as easy as this:

```css
#A {
  padding: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  max-width: 200px;
}
#B {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">
    Text<br />
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

You see a 1px space between `#A` and `#B`, you can lose that by setting the padding of `#A` to zero.

Comment: I see! This made perfect sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Place container A and B in a new container (lets call it C) and apply absolute position to A & B with 100% height. Container C will need relative position

```
.container-C {
   position: relative;
}
.container-A, .container-B {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now A and B will have the same height (the height of C). To bring B's content in "front" or over A, add z-index to both (more to B)

```
.container-A {
  z-index: 1;
}
.container-B {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: The height has to be varied, depending on the amount of content in B

Comment: In that case I believe you'll have to use JS to set height on A.